# Web app with infinit canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Need to implement really big graphic report with up to 5K elements on it (Gantt chart).
User must be able to **scroll through report** (scrollbar or mouse grab action) and **change scale**.

So far I came up with following ideas:

**Scrolling by mouse grab action**
Listen to user *mouse down* event and rerender the whole canvas on every mouse move (changed position) until *mouse up* event.

**Scroll bars**
Have to be custom made (also canvas or just html), also with event listeners on move action.

**Scale**
Could be implemented by using *canvas scale* property.

Do I think in right direction or there's a better (less code / more efficient) approach?

Comment: In my opinion, this is going in a _very_ wrong direction. Don't try to program UI in a canvas and reinvent the wheel, please use HTML like you would in a normal web application. Scaling is already possible through modern browsers via the zoom feature, typically located on the magnifying glass icon, so this isn't something you should need to implement yourself either.

Comment: I'm more concern about scrolling feature. Is it better to use SVG elements so browser will take care of all the scrolling and zooming? But won't it result in a poor perfomance when be used with lots of elements?

Comment: I fail to see what reason you have to believe that SVG will "take care" of scrolling and zooming any better than HTML elements will. As long as your CSS uses best practices, and any dynamic manipulation of the DOM is done with performance in mind (there are several blogs about high-performance CSS styling and DOM manipulation you can find by googling), there should not be any performance issues from simply having a lot of elements on the page.

Comment: I've just compared html/svg elements with browser supported scrolling and canvas implementation. I've got your point. Now I'm thinking of div elements mixed up with svg elements for more complex graphic elements.

Comment: I can not disagree with Anton more. For infinite zoom and scroll the DOM is slow, and worse the standard page navigation (scrollBars, wheel,  page zoom, and or touch) is atrocious. Though you have a lot of data the actual memory footprint is small. Rendering can be done on a canvas that is the size of the page, and with some careful  display render management (quadtree for visibility) a smooth 60FPS is easily attainable. You will be fighting the DOM all the way if you implement in HTML, with canvas you control the interface completely.

Comment: Still nor sure about canvas perfomanse even considering quadrants (what if user switch scale from min to max several times). As far as I know once SVG elements has been loaded application works quite fast.

Comment: @Anton Sorry Anton, my original comment was directed at Patrick Roberts, not you.  As for performance, that will all depend on the amount of data and how it is organised. When you zoom out things like text  or a 24hr period, becomes smaller, at some point you can't read it so generalise that information, text removed, 24hrs is rendered as a day.In the end it will come down you your skill set, If you are not comfortable with a technology and there is another available then use the one that best matches your skill set

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45389853/1693593) shows one (simplified) principle to achieve this and may perhaps be useful (see in full screen). Just replace drawn text with parts and offsets of the schema.